# c++ is there a built in partial_sort that returns the location of the sorted values

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, std

I have a list of N elements and want to find the ***location*** of the smallest (or largest) M values.
Is there a built in function (along the lines of std::sort or std::partial_sort) that does this?

Comment: If `N` is (very) large, `std::make_heap` of `M` elements out of the `N` values, where the values in the heap are pairs of the value and position.

Comment: Create a parallel array of indexes (i.e. 0,1,2,...) then (partial) sort the index array (based on the value in the original array that the index references).

Comment: Short answer: No, there's not anything built in to do that (though of course, yes, you can implement it yourself, and what's there makes it pretty easy).

Comment: @john: No need for sort/partial sort in this case. `std::nth_element` will suffice--and is normally linear instead of O(n log n).

Comment: @JerryCoffin the sizes I'mworking with now are about M between 2 and 10 and N~a few hundred. Will nth_element be faster than partial_sort? I also need the location (not the value), I don't see how nth_element gives that

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie would you still recommend make_heap for the size in my previous comment? I'd like to use the fastest option

Comment: You'd create the parallel array like @john suggested, then use `std::nth_element` to find the item at location `m` (call that the pivot). `nth_element` also partitions the array into elements not greater than the pivot to its left, and items not less than the pivot to its right. The index you stored in the parallel array will tell you the locations of those elements.

Comment: @unknown Since there will be just a few hundred elements, storing all of them in a single container would be ok.  If on the other hand you were getting hundreds of thousands, millions, or a constant stream of elements coming in, then maintaining a heap of M items would be a solution.  The heap elements would consist of the number and the position found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a built-in function.  But you can try something like this:

- Create a vector of iterators into your original array.  This will take much less place than an vector of pair<index, value>s, and will give you the fastest access to your original data, that's required for nth_element() to run as efficently as possible.
- Call std::nth_element() on your vector.
- Get indices by calling std::distance (or with subtraction, for c++98).

As in:

```
template <typename Fn>
std::vector<size_t> GetMElementsPositions(const std::vector<int>& v, size_t m,
                                          Fn&& compare) {
    assert(m != 0);
    assert(m <= v.size());

    std::vector<std::vector<int>::const_iterator> w;
    w.reserve(v.size());

    for (auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
        w.push_back(i);

    std::nth_element(w.begin(), w.begin() + M - 1, w.end(), [&compare](auto& x, auto& y) { return compare(*x, *y); });

    std::vector<size_t> r;
    r.reserve(M);
    for (auto i = w.begin(); i != w.begin() + M; ++i)
        r.push_back(std::distance(v.begin(), *i));

    return r;
}
```

You can also skip the std::distance()à part, and clip the result to size (or copy into a smaller array if M is a lot smaller than your original data set size.  Working with iterators is as easy as working with pointers, and a bit more efficient than using indices.

You will find a working prototype here: https://godbolt.org/z/YjjoanoTb